# Организация таблиц в Oracle БД в разрезе предметных областей

Tags: база-данных, oracle, архитектура, oracle11g, oracle12c

При переносе структуры данных из SQl Server на Oracle у меня появился вопрос об организации таблиц по предметным областям.

На SQL Server понятие схема хорошо ложиться на предметную область.

Например, что-то подобное:

```
Finance.Table1 ,  Finance.Table2,  Finance.Table3 ...
Production.Table1 ,  Production.Table2 ...
...
Branch_N.Table1, Branch_N.Table2, Branch_N.Table3...
```

При такой организации по схемам можно назначать права в разрезе схемы, это наглядно и работать легче. Есть минусы, но сейчас не об этом.

В Oracle схема более обособлена и я не уверен, что деление по схемам будет правильным.

Возможно ли в Oracle сделать похоже или стоит ограничиться префиксами, как-то так:

```
Finance$Table1 ,  Finance$Table2,  Finance$Table3 ...
Production$Table1 ,  Production$Table2 ...
...
Branch_N$Table1, Branch_N$Table2, Branch_N$Table3...
```

, ну или "_" вместо "$".

Но наглядность и удобство работы, при таком делении проигрывает делению из MS SQl.

Подскажите, как в Oracle принято организовывать таблицы по предметным областям?
Можно просто ссылку на "best practices" по этой части.

Comment: Тоже самое - Finance.Table1 итд. Почему вы считаете, что в Oracle схема более обособлена?  Обособлена от чего, или как?

Comment: Я исходил из того как MS предлагает маппить схехы оракл при обратной конвертации:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/mapping-oracle-schemas-to-sql-server-schemas-oracletosql?view=sql-server-ver15
Да и глядя на существующие схемы инстанса оракл той организации, куда нужно перенести БД из MS sql создаётся впечатление, что они больше похожи на БД в MS Sql.

Comment: А читая документацию по Оракл вижу, что схема связана с аккаунтом пользователя...

Comment: Да, в Oracle:  инстанс и БД 1:1, БД  и схема 1:м, схема и польз. 1:1. Но пока не вижу проблем в рамках вшего вопроса. Естъ Finance (это БД, как я понял), создаёте схему Finance и в ней таблицы Tab1, Tab2 итд. Может вы можете дать более  конкретный пример, где вы видите потребность в префиксах (они в любом случае bad practices).

Comment: Нет , Finance? Productions и т.д. , это схемы в БД MS Sql, но в MS Sql есть ещё БД , которые будут переносится и названия схем в этих БД могут быть одинаковыми (Например: БД Company1 и БД Company2 в них часть схем одинакова)., т.е. их придётся тащить на разные инстансы оракл?

Comment: Зависит от того, как эти БД между собой связаны. Но в общем случае, не на разные инстансы, а на разные БД1 -  Company1, БД2 - Company2 итд. У Оракла традиционно связь инстанс и БД m:1, а начиная с 12 версии m:m. Пока всё равно не совсем понимаю вопроса в целом.  Kак пoявившиеся CompanyN вписываются в вопрос об организации таблиц по предметным областям? Всё таки попробуйте конкретизировать вопрос небольшим примером.

Comment: Вот аналогичный документ по миграции [SQL Server to Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10405_01/appdev.120/e10379/ss_oracle_compared.htm). Вам все равно перед полной концепцией миграции надо будет делать proof of concept (или уже готова?), начните ее делать сейчас в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В отличии от SQl Server, схемы в Oracle связаны с определённым пользователем, имя схемы и пользователя совпадают. Так сложилось исторически, т.к. Oracle БД создавалась, когда известных на сегодняшний день норм и стандартов ещё не было.

Однако, не стоит ассоциировать имя пользователя с конкретным физическим лицом, например, "Вася" или "Маша". Имя пользователя, и соответственно схемы, выбирается в соответствии с терминами бизнес логики или технической реализации: "Finance", "Purchase", "Common", "Api" итд. То есть, как и указанно в вопросе - по предметным областям.

Данная "эволюция" именования схем прослеживается в схемах с примерами. Традиционную схему `SCOTT` (*Bruce Scott* автор и архитектор первых версий БД), которая больше не входит в комплет поставки, заменили, например на:

- `HR` - *Human resources*
- `OE` - *Order entry*
- `SH` - *Sales history*

Хотя в БД используются прфиксы, например - `SYS_`, `ORA_` и др., использовать префиксы для именования обьектов БД не рекомендуется. Следует воспользоваться рекомендациями:

- [Database Object Names and Qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-3C59E44A-5140-4BCA-B9E1-3039C8050C49) и
- [Qualified Names and Dot Notation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-name-resolution.html#GUID-688FB948-E8F0-4294-B2DF-4C281BCD366C)